# I am trying to export a list of all Teams with name and GroupID to a csv

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I am trying to export a list of all Teams with name and GroupID to a csv, but it gives me an error?

The code is :

```
1 Install-Module -Name MSOnline
2 Import-Module MsOnline
3 Connect-MsolService

4 Connect-MicrosoftTeams
5 $Teams = Get-Team 
6 ForEach ($Team in $Teams) 
7 { 
8        $TeamsArray = $TeamsArray + {Get-Team -groupid $team.groupid |Ft $team.DisplayName,  $team.GroupId, $team.Description;}
9 } 
10 $TeamsArray | Export-Csv -Path c:\Scripts\testfile1.csv
```

The error is:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.
At line:6 char:9
+         $TeamsArray = $TeamsArray + {Get-Team -groupid $team.groupid  ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (op_Addition:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

What is wrong ? :(

Comment: You'll probably want to define `$TeamsArray`, even as easy as `$TeamsArray = @()` would probably fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting all of the info you want in the "Get-Team" command, all you need to do is `Select-Object` it.

```
Install-Module -Name MSOnline
Import-Module MsOnline
Connect-MsolService

Connect-MicrosoftTeams
Get-Team | Select-Object DisplayName,  GroupId, Description | Export-Csv -Path c:\Scripts\testfile1.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: pffff so easy :D